# Integrate Mailchimp to a Contact Form 7 contact form

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7, plugin-mailchimp

Is there an elegant way (without [hacking the plugin's code](http://www.silenceit.ca/2011/02/28/how-to-integrate-mailchimp-with-contact-form-7)) to integrate a Contact Form 7 contact form to Mailchimp, so I can have a checkbox that when selected would register the email to a Mailchimp list?

Thank you

Comment: I've been trying to solve this one for days and some genius has made a plugin which made it so simple! No mucky code even better. :) http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-autoresponder-addon-plugin/other_notes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is what finally worked for me](http://www.silenceit.ca/2011/02/28/how-to-integrate-mailchimp-with-contact-form-7). The code needs to be updated tho. I don't have time now to get back to the refactored code but if someone requests it I will do it in due time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use my plugin called [MailChimp for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/) to do this.

When installed, you can select one or multiple lists in the plugin settings and use the following shortcode inside your Contact Form 7 templates.

`[mc4wp_checkbox "Your label text"]`

It will render a checkbox and when checked, subscribe the given email address to the MailChimp lists you selected.

*PS. I realize this question is over 2 years old. Just answering in case anyone else stumbles across it. Some answers had been given but I am pretty sure this is by far the easiest way to do it.*

Comment: This is pretty sweet, nice work!

Comment: Do you happen to know of a way to do this without the checkbox? I have a contact 7 contact form which is a "signup to the mailing list form", so I don't really want a check box to confirm, just want the user to be signed up when they click signup..?

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work for you...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/newsletter-sign-up/

You'll still possibly have to modify the contact form's files but only to do this:

"You can manually place the checkbox by calling  inside the form tags of your comment form."

Comment: It removed the code, this is the function you call:`<?php if(function_exists('nsu_checkbox')) nsu_checkbox(); ?> `

Comment: A little late but as I am the author of the plugin you mention, I just wanted to give a quick heads up that a better way would be to use my plugin that is developed specifically for MailChimp: [MailChimp for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/). 

It integrates with Contact Form 7 automatically, you can use `[mc4wp_checkbox "Your label text"]` inside your CF7 templates.